# My calculator is not out putting anything and not giving errors in any test?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have been working on a simple price calculator that determines monthly cost of support based on customer inputs. The customer puts in how many domains and users they have and this tells them our cost. I cannot get it to output a total.
http://jsfiddle.net/c8sjadd9/1/

```
function getUserPrice() {
    var userPrice = 0;
    var uPrice = 0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="users"
    var theForm = document.forms("priceform");
    var useNum = theForm.elements("users");

    if (useNum === 1 && useNum <= 5) {
        uPrice = 2.00;
    } else if (useNum >= 6 && useNum <= 10) {
        uPrice = 1.75;
    } else if (useNum >= 11 && useNum <= 15) {
        uPrice = 1.50;
    } else if (useNum >= 16 && useNum <= 25) {
        uPrice = 1.25;
    } else {
        uPrice = 1.00;
    }

    userPrice = theForm() * uPrice();
    //finally we return domainPrice
    return userPrice;
}

function getDomainPrice() {
    var domainPrice = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms("priceform");
    var domNum = theForm.elements("domains");

    domainPrice = domNum() * 8.00;

    return domainPrice;
}


function calculateTotal() {

    var totPrice = getUserPrice() + getDomainPrice();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display = 'block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Your Company's Price is: $" + totPrice;

}

function hideTotal() {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

I cannot get it to display the totals and I do not see anhing wrong with it.... Any suggestions?

Comment: I am seeing several variables in there where you have put `theForm()` instead of `theForm`. The parenthesis are only for function and method calls.

Comment: Have you done any dedugging? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: You should open a console in your browser and look at the errors you get. I already see two: `hideTotal is not defined` and `calculateTotal is not defined`

Comment: On your JSFiddle, you need to change the option in the upper left from "onload" to "no wrap - in head". That will fix part of the issue in the Fiddle

Comment: Also, `document.forms` and `form.elements` are Javascript collections. As such you need to use square brackets `[` and `]` to get individual items from the collection. So `document.forms["myform"]`

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think where you put `domainPrice = domNum() * 8.00;` maybe you were looking for the value of the field. So `domainPrice = domNum.value * 8.00;`

Comment: Added an answer with DEMO based on what I think could be problems in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of errors in your code, I'm adding this answer according to what I think there should be.

**1)** You should get forms like `document.forms["priceform"]` instead of `document.forms("priceform")` && elements like `form.element["domains"]` instead of `form.element("domains")`

**2)** You are saying `userPrice = theForm() * uPrice();` but I think there should be `useNum.value * uPrice` in function `getUserPrice()`, same problem in `getUserDomain()` also.

**3)** In your fiddle select `No-Wrap in HEAD` for your script.

[**FIXED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/c8sjadd9/5/)

**Console is your friend, make a habit of looking at it.**

I tried to point out problems but if there are still some let me know.

Comment: Yep. Everything @Mritunjay said